# Load custom product detail page instead of default in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-view

I am trying to remove default product detail page content, can i load custom phtml file for product detail page along with the image?

I need to remove all the default blocks of product detail page and show only my template content.

Is that can be done? Because i need to custom code in that template file to interact with external api with the product id.

How this can be achieved? Please anyone suggest me.

Comment: Yes , you can override a view files and achieve what you are looking for . create custom module/theme for this and override the core files . Please go through this it might help you - https://www.classyllama.com/blog/template-override-m2

Comment: You can remove the blocks from xml for your theme.

Comment: Please can you update me what code i need to add in catalog_product_view.xml file?

Comment: Hello @jafarpinjar, did you got your solution ?

Comment: no, i am trying the answer which is posted here, and confirm you once it worked.

Comment: Hello @jafarpinjar, did you tried my solution ? If have any issue, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of module, You just need to create a `catalog_product_view.xml` at:

> app/design/frontend/[Package]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.product.view" template="Magento_Catalog::product/customview.phtml" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main" remove="true"></referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" remove="true"></referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.details" remove="true"></referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
</body>
</page>
```

Create a `customview.phtml` at:

> app/design/frontend/[Package]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/customview.phtml

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo $product->getName();?> <!-- whatever you want -->
```

**Result will be:**
[image]

Comment: Nice, i used your code, its working great, but small change i need , i have created custom attribute for product called "is_custom", if that value is yes then i need to load this file else i need to use default one. is that can be checked and use?

Comment: Hello @jafarpinjar, Good to know that it worked. If you want to load this layout based on condition you can follow https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/news/magento-technical-notes-60/post/different-product-layout-based-on-product-custom-attribute-in-magento-2-630

Comment: if still you found any issue, Please let me know.

Comment: hello @pavan, i couldn't get from the above link, What i need exactly is i need to use that layout file code based on the product attribute value, i have created product attribute called 'is_custom' if it is set as Yes then i need to load the above phtml else i need to use default magento product detail page, is that can be done?

Answer (score 2):

This is to just give an idea, please change the code accordingly as the code is neither complete or verified.

Setup a new magento 2 extension.

Create `catalog_product_view.xml` on the following path

```
app/code/{YourVendor}/{YourExtension}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

with something like

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="{YourVendor}\{YourModule}\Block\Product\View" name="{vendor}.{module}.product.view" template="product/view.phtml" before="-"/>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main" remove="true"></referenceContainer>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Now Create a Block file `View.php` on path

```
app/code/{YourVendor}/{YourModule}/Block/Product/View.php
```

Extend magento's base block class for product view, something like

```
namespace {YourVendor}\{YourModule}\Block\Product;
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View {
    // DEFINE FUNCTIONS TO SUIT YOUR REQUIREMENTS OR OVERRIDE FUNCTIONS FROM VIEW CLASS
}
```

Also create the template file `view.phtml` on path

`app/code/{YourVendor}/{YourExtension}/view/frontend/templates/product/view.phtml`

You can use the functions you defined in the `View` Block class

Comment: hi. @Hammad,  I tried your code, from that i can only remove name and price details, but still i can see image and review section, i need to remove entirely all the default blocks of product detail page , ans i need to add my own code there, is that possible?

Comment: @jafarpinjar, if you open the main `catalog_product_view.xml ` file, you can see a lot of block created there, you will have to remove them as well. it is a good approach if you use the newly created xml file to remove them, rather than removing them from the main file

Comment: hi, @Hammad, yes i used your code only but, as i asked is it possible to do like that?

Comment: @jafarpinjar, that is what i mean with my above comment.. it is possible,  you just have to remove the default blocks loaded on the product pages

Comment: Please refer the link below for adding custom layouts https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251880/how-do-i-display-a-custom-grouped-product-page-layout/321857#321857